# Cors and preflight errors with axios in vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, oauth-2.0, axios, jwt

In my application I have got laravel as backend, jwt-auth as authentication, socialite as oauth2 provider and vue as my frontend.

Now I use axios to authorize the user by github for example (https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize) inside the client and then get the access token by the backend api.

If I do the authorize request with POSTMAN everything works, but if I do the request with my frontend axio request I get always errors. I think I get them because some Header values which are not correct. Can someone explain me which variables an axion request needs to perform an authorization request.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Which cors error are you getting? What request are you getting it on, to your own server or github's? If to github then the api probably isnt meant to be consumed client side, if to your server then you need to add the right header for an OPTIONS request

Comment: I can use it with postman. I think if github isnt meant to be consumed client side it would also not work. I am getting this error: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect) when I do a get request. This is the request: 
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=myclientid&redirect_uri=redirect&scope=user%3Aemail&response_type=code&state=randomstate this is explained here:https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/

Comment: Postman works because it ignores CORS, CORS headers are used by the browser to determine wither or not a request is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

you can either disable cors in your browser which is very bad or you have to enable cors in your backend and to check if cors is enabled in your backend look for Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in browser network tab or you have to use proxy so that the requests are made to the same origin as seen by the browser but are redirected to some other url.

```
In create-react-app this works by adding
"proxy":"http://youUrl:portNo."
```